# @Value Integer variable in Spring Controller Causes a jUnit Error (jUnit does not use this variable)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit

I have a strange error in my jUnit for a SpringMVC Controller which has a `@Value` `Integer` class variable:

```
@Value("${max.insert.participants.batch.size}")
private Integer maxInsertParticipantsBatchSize;
```

**The setting comes from a Properties file (all other settings are also read properly from it)**

```
max.insert.participants.batch.size=1000
```

This is a variable from a Properties file. It is **not** used or checked in the jUnit, but the jUnit fails with:

```
12:38:21 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${max.insert.participants.batch.size}"
12:38:21    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[?:?]
```

As soon as I change the `@Value` type to a `String` or a `Boolean` the jUnit starts working. For instance

```
@Value("${max.insert.participants.batch.size}")
private String maxInsertParticipantsBatchSize;
```

Once again, the jUnit does not use this variable. It is only used in the actual application.

Comment: The test loads it, but apparently there is no value for property or property replacement isn't active for your test and hence it will fail (as it cannot convert).

Comment: Can you please provide your test class code for more information?

Comment: So actually I am providing the value in the Properties file. It's there. I also updated my OP to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

If your test case is a unit test then this will not work. As the spring context does not get initialized with the unit test. The way you can use the value of this variable in the unit test is by setting the variable value like this.

`ReflectionUtils.setField(fieldName, object, value);`

If your test case is a component test case where spring context is getting initialized then you need to supply the value in your application property file like this

`max.insert.participants.batch.size:3`

you can also provide a default value like this

`@Value("${max.insert.participants.batch.size:3}")
private Integer maxInsertParticipantsBatchSize;`

The default value will be overwritten with the value you provide in the application property file.